# What was Mahaprabhu's view on taking sannyasa?

Tags: chaitanya, sannyasa

Did Maahaprabhu Sri Chaitanya advise His followers to take sannyasa? What was His view on sannyasa? Did He give sannyasa to anybody?

I am interested to know this because most of His followere in these days are seen wearing gerua clothes.Are they following some orders of Mahaprabhu?

Kindly cite proper sources.

**No answer quoting the Madhva sect or ISKCONites please as I want authentic sources linked directly with Mahaprabhu, like His and His direct disciples' biographies,and writings.**